# How to output items from an array in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Im really new to angular. And I find that it is really hard to get an item from an array and output in the relevant html file in that component.
The below code shows the onClick function of the ***bill-item.component.ts*** file

```
arr: Array<any> =[];
itemArray: Array<any> =[]; 

     onAddToBill(itemId:string, name:string , expireDate:string , quantity:string){

      this.itemArray.push([itemId,name,expireDate,quantity]);
      this.arr.push(this.itemArray);
      console.log(this.arr);

      }
```

And I need to output the item array on my ***bill-item.component.html*** which is shown below

```
                 <tbody>

                  <tr *ngFor="let itemArrays of arr">

                    <td *ngFor="let obj of itemArrays">{{obj[1]}}</td>
                    <td *ngFor="let obj of itemArrays">{{obj[0]}}</td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="is-center" id="number" value="1" style="width: 50%;" /></td>
                    <td *ngFor="let obj of itemArrays">{{obj[2]}}</td>
                    <td *ngFor="let obj of itemArrays">{{obj[3]}}</td>

                  </tr>

                </tbody>
```

The below image shows the item list when I add the first item

[image: after adding one item]

But after adding the second item , the item list shows like this
[image: The name of the item should be in a separate row not in the same row as first item]

Here all the items gets add up to the same row , I want to get each item in separate row , line after line.

Then I tried the below code

```
           <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let entries of arr">
                <td>{{entries [1]}}</td>
                <td>{{entries [0]}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="is-center" id="number" value="1" style="width: 50%;" /></td>
                <td>{{entries [2]}}</td>
                <td>{{entries [3]}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

[image]

And this was the result. As ID has the entry[0] it was filled with all the instances in that array.

The below image shows my console.log(arr) result after adding 3 items
[image]

[image]

Comment: what's the problem /error you are facing??

Comment: Sorry I updated the issues. @ShlokNangia

Comment: IMO replacing the inner array with an object would make more sense. Especially since you're trying to render the elements in an order different to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily get values from "itemArray" rather than use "arr" and get the item details and print in table.

```
<table>
      <tr *ngFor="let x of itemArray">
          <td>{{x[0]}}</td>
          <td>{{x[1]}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

like wise

Comment: Kollo this actually worked , thanks a lot for saving the time.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to use `*ngFor` for each of entries as you are using array indexes like `entries[1]`

```
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let entries of arr">
                <td>{{entries [1]}}</td>
                <td>{{entries [0]}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="is-center" id="number" value="1" style="width: 50%;" /></td>
                <td>{{entries [2]}}</td>
                <td>{{entries [3]}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

I tried this above code with following value of `arr`

```
arr = [['a','b','c','d'],['a1','b1','c1','d1']]
```

and got the result as

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but here in my "arr" array I'm storing "itemArray" which is the array storing [ itemId , name , expireDate , quantity ] , so " arr " is like an 2 D array , if im not mistaken it. So entries[0] = [ itemId , name , expireDate , quantity ] but i need only the ItemID for entries[0]

Comment: no, entries= [ itemId , name , expireDate , quantity ] (i.e. each entry of arr) and entries[0] =ItemID

Comment: as entries is each element in for loop

Comment: entries is one instance of arr array, but my arr array has [itemArray1,itemArray2, itemArray3] where itemArray=[itemId,name,expireDate,quantity] , Please look at my bill-item.component.ts code shown in the above question

Comment: check this https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data

Comment: I ran the code given by you and updated the question with the result I got.

Comment: can you please add value of `arr` to ques??

Comment: @LalanaChamika check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213843/discussion-between-lalana-chamika-and-shlok-nangia).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for iterating `itemArrays`. You can directly access element using the `index`.

Remove `*ngFor` of each `itemArrays` on each row.

```
<tbody>

              <tr *ngFor="let itemArrays of arr">
                <td>{{itemArrays[1]}}</td>
                <td >{{itemArrays[0]}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="is-center" id="number" value="1" style="width: 50%;" /></td>
                <td >{{itemArrays[2]}}</td>
                <td>{{itemArrays[3]}}</td>

              </tr>

            </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but here in my "arr" array Im storing "itemArray" which is the array storing [ itemId , name , expireDate , quantity ] , so " arr " is like an 2 D array , if im not mistaken it. So itemArrays[0] = [ itemId , name , expireDate , quantity ] but i need only the ItemID for itemArrays[0]

Answer (score 0):

In `td` you are already accessing the items in the array, so you do not need to use *ngFor.

```
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let itemArrays of arr">
                <td>{{itemArrays[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{itemArrays[0]}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" class="is-center" id="number" value="1" style="width: 50%;" /></td>
                <td>{{itemArrays[2]}}</td>
                <td>{{itemArrays[3]}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but here in my "arr" array Im storing "itemArray" which is the array storing [ itemId , name , expireDate , quantity ] , so " arr " is like an 2 D array , if im not mistaken it. So itemArrays[0] = [ itemId , name , expireDate , quantity ] but i need only the ItemID for itemArrays[0]